# Create thumbnail for each page of document

Tags: javascript, html, widget

I am trying to create a thumbnail widget that, when fed a document as a url, will show a thumbnail for each page of the document; The number of pages should be configurable (10, 20, 50 pages etc.).

The problem I face is how to direct a thumbnail to show an intermediate page of the document, such as page 5, instead of just showing the cover page, which is the default option. Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: How are you creating it now? Can you show some code?

Answer (score 0):

You could use HTML anchors like this :

```
<div id="page1">page 1</div>
<div id="page2">page 2</div>
<div id="page3">page 3</div>
<div id="page4">page 4</div>
<div id="page5">page 5</div>
```

and to browse to page 5 on the same HTML page create a link like this :

```
<a href="#page5">Go to page 5</a>
```

Comment: How do I assign the pages so that it knows that "page4" means the fourth page of the document? The document is dynamic, so it has to work for any random document that can be shown as a collection of pages.